# psql format date to display "week W"

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-formatting

According to this Data Type Formatting document for Postgres
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html

`W` will allow it to display week of month (1-5).
But is there a way for me to escape the "w" in string "week"?

So I can specify `"\week W"`, and
it displays "week 1", "week 2", etc.

I know I can do string concatenation afterwards, but would like to avoid unnecessary complexity if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, '"week" w');
```

You could add any text/Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks in your format model.

> [Usage notes for date/time formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html):
>
> ......
>
> Ordinary text is allowed in to_char templates and will be output
> literally. You can put a substring in double quotes to force it to be
> interpreted as literal text even if it contains pattern key words. For
> example, in '"Hello Year "YYYY', the YYYY will be replaced by the year
> data, but the single Y in Year will not be. In to_date, to_number, and
> to_timestamp, double-quoted strings skip the number of input
> characters contained in the string, e.g. "XX" skips two input
> characters.